# Exchange setup with dual Mailbox/DAG role

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010, cluster

I inherited a newly created Exchange 2010 environment that has two servers with dual Mailbox and DAG roles on each, basically trying to accomplish the failover clustering that Exchange 2003 had. Management seems to think it's perfectly fine since it "seems" to work, but I'm kind of skeptical. Does anyone know if this configuration is supported or acceptable? I'd like to just change to a separate single role mailbox server and DAG server, but I need some kind of supporting evidence.

Comment: All of this is in the microsoft documentation. DAGs are most certainly best practice.

Comment: I guess I didn't clarify, my point is that the DAGs are being used as the primary mailbox servers. Not for DR.

Answer (score 2):

A DAG isn't an Exchange role. A DAG is a configuration that allows two or more mailbox servers to host a copy of one or more mailbox databases. What you're describing sounds perfectly normal. Each Mailbox server participating in the DAG will have a copy of the mailbox database(s) that have been added to the DAG.

http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-2010-database-availability-group-installation-step-by-step

http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/how-move-single-server-high-availability-dag.html

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351172(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: Semantics or not, I have never read about anyone using DAGs as their primary mailbox servers.

Comment: You're not understanding what a DAG is. A DAG is a configuration that allows two or more mailbox database servers to host a copy of a mailbox database. A DAG IS NOT a role. A non-mailbox database server cannot be a DAG member because it DOES NOT host any mailbox databases. Sorry for the CAPS but I'm trying to emphasize the point that a DAG IS NOT A ROLE. You can configure the DAG any way you like in terms of which DAG member hosts the active copy of the database and which holds the passive copy but at the end of the day a DAG member is a mailbox database server.

Comment: It's not semantics - you've got a serious misunderstanding. Think of a DAG as a cluster (in fact, it does use part of the MS cluster stack.) Now that you've got a cluster, you put your mailbox databases into it.

Comment: Jinx, @joeqwerty

Comment: You owe me a coke.

Comment: Dammit. (more chars)